# Show that the abelian group of the $p$-adic integers is torsion free

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that the $p$-adic integers is torsion-free, but I am not sure if my proof is correct.

Here I'm thinking about the inverse limit definition of $p$-adic integers. Thus I want to show that there does not exists an element that looks like a sequence $\{a_i\}_{i \ge 1}$ such that $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $a_i \equiv a_j$ for $i \le j$.

Let $n < \infty$ such that $n \cdot (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. This means that $a_i n = p^i$ for all $i\ge 1$. 
Thus $n = 1$ or $p$.

If $n = 1$, then $a_i = p^i$ for all $i$ and hence $(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.

If $n = p$, then $a_i p = p^i$ implies that $a_i = p^{i-1}$ for all $i$, but $a_i \not\equiv a_j$ for $i \le j$ so this element is not in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

Is this the correct way to see it?

Comment: Before starting... You should probably be explicit in your question on what is your definition of the $p$-adic integers. Are you thinking "inverse limit"? Are you thinking some kind of formal infinite sum? What are the $a_i$?

Comment: @peterag. Hello! Thanks for the comment! I'm using the inverse limit definition of $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: It seems to me that, where you wrote $a_in=p^i$, what you really have is that $a_in$ is divisible by $p^i$.

Comment: Doesn't the inverse limit construction of $p$-adic integers dictate that $a_i\in\Bbb{Z}/p^i\Bbb{Z}$ instead of $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think it must just be a typo, if only because of  the "If $n=1$, then $a_i = p^i$ ... " that follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete argument to show "torsion-free-ness,"  as I think you only want a comment on the part of the argument that you have given.

Your $n=1$ case is fine, although it might be a bit neater to write $a_i=0\in {\mathbb Z}/p^i{\mathbb Z}$ - but of course $0=p^i \in {\mathbb Z}/p^i{\mathbb Z}$.

But your $n=p$ case/conclusion is not  correct... One has $a_i = p^{i-1}b_i$,  for some $b_i$, for $i\ge 2$. On the other hand, relabeling, one has $$a_{j+1} = p^j b_{j+1} \equiv a_j,$$ for all $j\ge 1$. Therefore $a_j=0\in {\mathbb Z}/p^j{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: I had this 'answer' first only as a 'comment.' I moved it down here, to remove the question from the un-answered queue.

Comment: Some of my congruences and equalities notation [where do they live?]  is  a little bit sloppy here - I hope you know what I mean!  But let me know if things aren't clear...